# Redirect to previous page following user registration with Rails and Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I have a small Rails 3 app that uses sorcery for User authentication.  When a non authenticated user visits page 'A', they are restricted from viewing portions of the page unless they are logged in or register.

If they select the 'register' link they are taken to a separate Registration page, and on successful registration they are logged in and redirected to the home page.  I need them to be directed back to page 'A'.

This is my User.create controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.registration_notification(@user).deliver
    auto_login(@user)
    redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Registration successful!  You are now logged in."
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

I'm assuming the `redirect_back_or_to` bit is where the magic should happen but I'm missing something - currently this just redirects to the home page.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Do I need to pass a current page parameter to the controller or something?

Answer (score 0):

> I need them to be directed back to page 'A'.

Maybe this can help?

```
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - That just take me back to the register page.